# Upgrade to LibreOffice 5.2.2

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation, libreoffice

I just saw that `Libreoffice 5.2.2` is released. I have download the *.taz.gz* DEB files. Now I need to know how to upgrade it. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Should I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice
```

Also after that how do I install all the DEBs?

http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?version=5.2&lang=en-US#change

Linux (x64) DEB version.

Comment: Can you link the file you downloaded? That way I can give you an exact answer to your question.

Comment: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?version=5.2&lang=en-US#change

Linux (x64) DEB version.

Comment: Downloading it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove your old version

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
```

I am going to assume that you have the file in your Downloads folder, if not, please change to the correct folder.

In a terminal change to Downloads and then extract the package

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvzf LibreOffice_5.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
```

This will make a folder called `LibreOffice_5.2.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS`, so now change to that folder

```
cd LibreOffice_5.2.2.2_Linux_x86-64_deb/DEBS
```

Now we can install all those debs with this command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: If this work for you, please click the checkmark on the left, to allow users to identify this was the correct answer :) You are welcome.

Comment: There is also a PPA.

Comment: @fkraiem You mean this https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-prereleases Yes but I was hesitant to suggest it because I don't know what will happen when the version moves to full release, I could not find the information and did not want to suggest something that may be a problem down the line.

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Not sure what you mean by "when the version moves to full release"; packages for 5.2.2 release are not available yet, but they should be available shortly, and then those who have installed the 5.2.2-rc1 packages will get them as an upgrade.

Comment: That is what I mean, the PPA has the release candidates but I was just unsure if that PPA would update to a full release or not when it goes to full version. I think the actual final version will only go to the main PPA and it just seemed confusing to suggest swapping PPA's down the line.@fkraiem

Comment: TY for instructions I'll try it tonight. +1 on your path to 10k club :)